# Vim: Change colour depending on indentation/control flow depth?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, background-color, indentation, control-flow

In vim, is it possible to change the background colour of the line depending on the depth of the control flow, or of the indentation (which ever is easier)? I seem to remember seeing such a feature in an editor I used previously, but I can't find which one.

I use a light-on-dark scheme, and would like to change the background to get slightly lighter with each indentation step, and then obviously darker again as the code steps back out to higher levels.

Ideally it would be possible to just change the background of the line-number columns, or just the indentation (I use spaces only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Vim Indent Guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides) should be adequate.

Comment: You got it, that's better than anything I was imagining. Thanks!